# Mostrar a saída de um vetor customizada

Tags: php, loop, for

Tenho um vetor com 16 elementos. Eu quero mostrar os elementos desse vetor usando o laço de repetição `for`.
A saída deve se igual a esta:

```
A
1
2
3
4
B
A
5
6
7
8
B
A
9
10
11
12
B
A
13
14
15
16
B
```

Como terminou o laço, não há a necessidade de mostrar o **"A"** logo abaixo do último **B**.
Uma observação: eu somente dei o valor 16 como exemplo, mas pode ser qualquer valor, **como por exemplo: 4, 5, 17, 25, 30, 100, etc.**
Eu tentei este código:

```
for($k = 0, $i = 0; $k <= 16 ; $k++, $i++){
  if($k % 4)==0){
      echo "A";
  }
  //Mostrar os números aqui
   if($k % 5)==0){
      echo "B";
  }
}
```

https://repl.it/@TaffarelXavier/ForDemo

mas sem sucesso algum.

Comment: Não seria só trocar o `$k <= 16` para `$k <= 15`?!

Comment: Não, visto que 16 é somente um número como exemplo, mas poderia ser qualquer número, como mostrei na pergunta. Poderia ser 4, 5,17 ,26, 40, 100,1000, etc.

Comment: Por que você definiu `$i` no laço se você nem o utilizou? Se você precisa exibir também o número, por que não colocou `echo $k`? Por que começa exibindo `A` e não exibe `B`, visto que `0 % 5` será 0?

Comment: Corrigi, tirando o $i, mas, na verdade, eu não estou conseguindo criar a lógica. Gostaria muito de mostrar a saída da forma mencionada.

Comment: O problema é que não está claro qual é a lógica para definir a "forma mencionada".

Comment: Resolvi. Mas muito obrigado por tentarem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Acredito que poderia simplesmente fazer um array com os números (`range`) e dividi-lo (`array_chunk`):

```
<?php

$divisor = 4;
$maximo = 16;

foreach(array_chunk(range(1, $maximo), $divisor) as $k) {
  echo "A" . PHP_EOL;
  echo implode($k, PHP_EOL) . PHP_EOL;
  echo "B" . PHP_EOL;
}
```

[Pode testar isto aqui.](https://repl.it/repls/EmotionalKookyMouse)

```
A
1
2
3
4
B
A
5
6
7
8
B
A
9
10
11
12
B
A
13
14
15
16
B
```

Comment: Deu certo também. Obrigado, meu amigo.

Answer (score 3):

Não sei se entendi bem a sua dúvida, mas atualizei o [seu código](https://repl.it/repls/AlarmedUnfoldedPrinters), conforme a saida esperada que você postou.

inicialmente imaginei que seria impresso BA apenas para os múltiplos de 4 e 5, mas vi que  na verdade a lógica é para imprimir a cada 5 iterações.

```
<?php
     include 'professores.php';

     $total = count($Plugins['professores']['plugins']);
     $count = 0;
     for($k = 0; $k <= $total ; $k++){  
         if ($k == 0){
            echo "A";
            echo "\n" ;
         } else if($count == 5){      
               echo "B";
               echo "\n";
               echo "A";
               echo "\n";
               echo $k;
               echo "\n";
               $count = 0;
          } else {    
               echo $k;
              echo "\n";
          }
          $count++;
     }
     echo "B";
?>
```

Comment: Vou verificar. Obrigado.

Comment: ;) 
que bom meu velho!!!!
não esquece de avaliar a resposta meu caro!

Comment: Deu certo também. Obrigado.

Answer (score 3):

Também fiz mas sem usar contador, apenas condições, fica aqui como mais um exemplo.

```php
for($k = 0; $k <= 16; $k++){

  if(((($k-1) % 4) == 0 && ($k-1) != 0) || $k == 0){
      echo "A";
      echo PHP_EOL;
  }

    echo $k;
    echo PHP_EOL;

  if($k % 4 == 0 && $k != 0){
    echo "B";
    echo PHP_EOL;
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Fiz um exemplo mais simples, de uma olhada e veja se é o que você está querendo..

```
include 'professores.php';

$count = count($Plugins['professores']['plugins']);

//Contador de 4 em 4 adiciona um AB
$contador = 0;

//Tamanho do for a percorrer
$size = 16;
for($k = 1; $k <= $size ; $k++){

  //Se for o primeiro adiciona A antes
  if($k == 1)
    echo "A\n";

  // Se Contador == 4 e $k diferente do tamanho do vetor ele printa AB e zera o contador
  if($contador==4 && $k != $size ){
    echo "A\n";
    echo "B\n";
    $contador = 0;
  }

  //Imprime  $k
  echo "$k".PHP_EOL;

  // Se $k == Size printa B
  if($k == $size){
    echo "B\n";
  }

  //Incrementa contador
  $contador++;
}
?>
```

Comment: Ótimo, ótimo! Muito obrigado. Deu certo.